# ReduxObservable cancellation based on action type and its data

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have React app which uses redux-observable with typescript. In this scenario, FetchAttribute Action gets triggered with a id and then make an ajax call. 
In certain case, I would want to cancel the ajax request if "FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_CANCEL" action was triggered with the same id as of "FetchAttributeAction" action.

```
action$.ofType(FETCH_ATTRIBUTE)
    .switchMap((request: FetchAttributeAction) => {

      return ajax.getJSON(`/api/fetch-attribute?id=${request.id}`)
        .flatMap((fetchUrl) => {
            // return new action
        })
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_CANCEL));
    });

interface FetchAttributeAction{
  id: number;
}
```

Problem:
How do we cancel the execution based on action type + action data?
In my case, it would FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_CANCEL and id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to filter actions in the `takeUntil` notifier to only those which match the ID you care about.

`action$.ofType(FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_CANCEL).filter(action => action.id === request.id)`

So here's what it might look like:

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-xztkoo?file=fetchAttribute.js

```
const fetchAttributeEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_ATTRIBUTE)
    .mergeMap(request =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/fetch-attribute?id=${request.id}`)
        .map(response => fetchAttributeFulfilled(response))
        .takeUntil(
          action$.ofType(FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_CANCEL).filter(action => action.id === request.id)
        )
    );
```

You can also take a look at previous questions:

- [Redux Observable: If the same action is dispatched multiple times, how do I cancel one of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528620/redux-observable-if-the-same-action-is-dispatched-multiple-times-how-do-i-canc)
- [Independent chain cancellation in redux-observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966806/independent-chain-cancellation-in-redux-observable)
- [Dispatch an action in response to cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032226/dispatch-an-action-in-response-to-cancellation)

---

The OP also pointed out that they were using `switchMap` (as did I originally when I copied their code) which would have meant that the epic only ever had one getJSON at a time since `switchMap` will unsubscribe from previous inner Observables. So that also needed to be chained. Good catch!

Comment: Of course, there was a bug and its because of use of switchMap. I modified your code and its reproducible there too. https://stackblitz.com/edit/redux-observable-playground-v6dhlc {
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "@@redux/INIT"
    },
    {
      "type": "FETCH_ATTRIBUTE",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "type": "FETCH_ATTRIBUTE",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "type": "FETCH_ATTRIBUTE",
      "id": "22"
    },
    {
      "type": "FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_FULFILLED",
      "response": {
        "response": "/api/fetch-attribute?id=22"
      }
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Still works for me in that link. Did you maybe forget to save? But yes, you are right that if you use `switchMap` you'll have implicit cancellation--this epic will only ever have one pending getJSON. If you want concurrent you can use `mergeMap`. I didn't notice that in your OP lol nice catch!!

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to make takeUntil selective for a certain action id with pluck and filter.

ex:

```
.takeUntil(action%.ofType(FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_CANCEL)
.pluck('id')
.filter((cancelActionID) => cancelActionID === fetchID))
```

The non-obvious part to me is how to get the current fetchID to run that comparison. I might consider try using do to store in a temporary variable

Comment: How is above solution different than below code? It didn't work for me. ```return ajax.getJSON('/api/fetch-attribute?id='+request.id)
    .flatMap((fetchUrl) => {
        // return new action
    })
    .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_ATTRIBUTE_CANCEL).filter(action => action.payload === request.id));
});```

Comment: That's pretty much what I recommended to do. Are you sure you're getting the correct request.id inside that filter function? Have you tested whether firing that cancel action (through a button or something) is able to shut down the execution of that ajax call correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's getting correct request.id and when cancel action is fired it shut down the execution. I have tested this using console.log statements