# How to compare actions data in Observable stream?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using Redux and have problem with RxJs.

Let's say that one action was fired 3 times (type: 'OPEN') during 2 secs. Action is sending some data to Redux state. First and third fired are bringing the same data, but second not.  All of them have delays before coming to bring some effects.

I want Observable to notice, that action 1 and action 3 have the same data and change the order of output. From 1, 2, 3 => 2, 3. The first one should be deleted because of action nr 3.

```
 const closeNotificationAuto = action$ =>
    action$
       .ofType(OPEN)
       .mergeMap(action =>
            Observable.of(action)
              .delay(5000)
              .map(() => closeAuto())
              .takeUntil(
      action$.ofType(CLOSE).filter(a => a.something === action.something)
    )
);
```

QUESTION:  How to compare an active streams in Observable?

Comment: If you want to filter a current action based on future actions then you have to buffer your actions for some period of time. After that period has expired then you could filter and emit. You could do this with one of the buffer operators or on completion. Given your specific usecase with redux I am left wondering why you would want to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because I want to restart the delay time for an action which is the same that previous. Don't know if it is possible. In my code above, there is a chance that two OPEN actions with the same content will be in progress. e.g.  action OPEN with data 'first' was dispatched. After 3s action OPEN with data 'first' is dispatched again. So I have two the same actions in one time. I want to abort the first one and left only the second but while I am using action.content  in  CLOSE action I need to abort delay time from first action because it will remove my second action after 2 s instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in redux-observable to prevent/delete dispatched actions or modify the order of them because by the time they reach your epics they have already been run through your reducers and any other middleware. This is by design to make it so that epics themselves are the only place that nondeterminism should happen; it also means that you can know for certain that the redux store's state has been updated when you receive them in your epics.

If you can elaborate a bit on the use case I may be able to recommend alternative approaches.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear enough. My fault. What I am trying to achieve is avoid of listening actions with the same data. The goal of OPEN action is to show a notification with a specific content on user screen. e.g. two buttons => both are dispatching OPEN action but first with a content of 'First' and second 'Second'.

Test: click btn1, btn2, btn1. On screen: 'First'    'Second'    'First'

In reducer I filter those data and left the latest 'Second'    'Filter' on screen.

The problem is that I can't stop the stream of first click in epic. Is it possible to abort stream with same data?

Comment: Maybe a comment that I post above to answer bygrace user will be useful.

Comment: @Franz If your desire is to not have duplicate notifications on your screen then I would suggest sourcing your notifications from your ngrx store. In your reducer you can remove or replace an existing equivalent notification. Or you could even do the filtering and buffering in a projection off of state. I think that either of those options would be more appropriate and possible than doing what you want in an effect.

Comment: Adding second takeUntil is solving the problem:

.takeUntil( action$.ofType(OPEN).filter(a => a.name === action.name))

Now when I want to dispatch an OPEN action with the same data/name the previous stream is cancelled.